# Force app to use google speech synthesis

Tags: android, text-to-speech, google-text-to-speech

I have built an app that uses Text-To-Speech. When I install it on a phone, it will automatically download the google output speech synthesis voices. But in some phones it doesn't. How can I force on ALL phones to download it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Try this constructor:

`TextToSpeech tts = new TextToSpeech(context, TextToSpeech.OnInitListener, "com.google.android.tts");`

It will be applied **over API 14**.

You can force to use specific tts engine by input engine's package name at last parameter of `TextToSpeech` constructor.

And, package name of Google TTS is "com.google.android.tts".

Also, if you want to use another engine for force the app, you can find package names of installed tts engine in your device with this method: `TextToSpeech.getEngines()`;

It will be returned a list of `EngineInfo` instance about tts engines in device.

Comment: Thank you! We had some users in countries outside the US who were reporting some text-to-speech features in our app weren't working. Turns out that Samsung and other manufacturers have their own text-to-speech engines that they default their devices to. Surprise, surprise, their TTS engines are broken and don't work for all languages. Changed to default to Google and now it works for everyone.